# SQS lambda integration- Lambda not getting any messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have lambda function which read sqs messages and process it. I have implement a trigger(lambda trigger) for the integration .

Each time when I push a message to the queue Lambda is getting invoked and from the logs **I understood that all the messages are in in-flight status** .

```
 String queueUrl = sqs.getQueueUrl("test_queue").getQueueUrl();
       final ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new 
  ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl);
        int count = getMessagesCount(sqs);

        while(messagesCount > 0) {
            List<Message> messages = 

sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();

 logger.info("No.of messages in queue :{} ", count);
```

See the logs [image]

Lambda time out and sqs visibility timeout are 20 minutes.
SQS configuration is given below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use SQS integration with Lambda, AWS handles polling the queue for messages and sending them to the Lambda function. The message is in-flight because AWS has already retrieved the message for you. You shouldn't be calling `sqs.receiveMessage`. You shouldn't even need to use the SQS API at all. The message is in the `event` object passed to your Lambda function when it is invoked. All you need to do is process the message.

Comment: Are you saying that I will get all the information from   "requestInput"                                     
     @Override
    public ResponseOutput apply(Object requestInput) {

Comment: Yes, what you are naming `requestInput` is the event object passed to your Lambda invocation. It will contain one or more SQS messages.

Comment: Thanks Mark,you saved my day. One more question,in this case we don't need to remove the message manually rite?Can we remove the message With out calling SQS API ?

Comment: All your questions are answered on this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html I suggest taking a few minutes to read that to familiarize yourself with how Lambda SQS integration works. To answer your question, when your Lambda function invocation completes without throwing an error, the messages will be automatically deleted from the queue for you.